# python & tkinter : the Text widget I'm using doesn't "pack"

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, text-widget

I have a question as to why my text windget doesn't pack properly in this piece of code. For the record it's supposed to read a log file in the users Documents folder, and display the contents in the Text widget, coloring red warnings and errors and blue informations. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here's the new code I came up with, but the Text widget doesn't pack inside the main frame...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time
from os.path import expanduser

def get_log_path():
    p = ""
    if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
        p = expanduser("~/.local/share/binding of isaac afterbirth+/log.txt")
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        p = expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Binding of Isaac Afterbirth+/log.txt")
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        p = expanduser("~/Documents/My Games/binding of isaac afterbirth+/log.txt")
    return p
    pass

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.start_stop = False
        self.log_path = get_log_path()
        self.output = tk.Text(self)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(master)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Start", command=self.start)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Stop", command=self.stop)
        master.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.oldline = "  "
        self.init_layout()
        pass

    def init_layout(self):
        self.output.config(font="sans 12", width=200, height=60, state = tk.DISABLED)
        self.output.tag_config("error", foreground="#FF0000")
        self.output.tag_config("info", foreground="#0000FF")
        self.output.pack()
        self.readfile()
        pass

    def readfile(self):
        if self.start_stop:
            tmp = self.log_f.readline().lower()
            if self.oldline != tmp: #display spam only once@FileLoad
                if "err" in tmp or "error" in tmp or "warn" in tmp and not "overlayeffect" in tmp and not "animation" in tmp: #Error filter to display
                    #print(tmp, end='', file=sys.stderr)
                    self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp)
                    index = "end - 1 lines"
                    self.output.tag_add("error", index)
                elif "lua" in tmp:
                    self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp)
                    index = "end - 1 lines"
                    self.output.tag_add("info", index)
                self.oldline = tmp
            self.after(5, self.readfile)
            pass
        pass
    def start(self):
        self.log_f = open(self.log_path, "r")
        self.start_stop = True
        self.readfile()
        pass
    def stop(self):
        self.log_f.close()
        self.start_stop = False
        pass
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Isaac Debug Helper")
    root.geometry("650x500")
    gui = GUI(root)
    gui.mainloop()
```

And there's the old code for reference :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time
from os.path import expanduser

def get_log_path():
    p = ""
    if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
        p = expanduser("~/.local/share/binding of isaac afterbirth+/log.txt")
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        p = expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Binding of Isaac Afterbirth+/log.txt")
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        p = expanduser("~/Documents/My Games/binding of isaac afterbirth+/log.txt")
    return p
    pass

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.start_stop = True
        self.log_path = get_log_path()
        self.output = tk.Text(self)
        self.frame=tk.Frame()
#       self.reloadButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Reload", command=self.reload)
        self.startButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.stopButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.oldline = "  "
        self.init_layout()
        pass

    def init_layout(self):
        self.output.pack(side=tk.LEFT)#, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.output.config(font="sans 12", width=200, height=60, state = tk.DISABLED)
        self.output.tag_config("error", foreground="#FF0000")
        self.output.tag_config("info", foreground="#0000FF")
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
#       self.reloadButton.pack(in_=self.frame)
        self.startButton.pack(in_=self.frame)
        self.stopButton.pack(in_=self.frame)
        self.readfile()
        pass

    def readfile(self):
        if self.start_stop:
            with open(self.log_path, "r") as f:
                tmp = f.readline().lower()
                if self.oldline != tmp: #display spam only once@FileLoad
                    if "err" in tmp or "error" in tmp or "warn" in tmp and not "overlayeffect" in tmp and not "animation" in tmp: #Error filter to display
                        #print(tmp, end='', file=sys.stderr)
                        self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp)
                        index = "end - 1 lines"
                        self.output.tag_add("error", index)
                    elif "lua" in tmp:
                        self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp)
                        index = "end - 1 lines"
                        self.output.tag_add("info", index)
                    self.oldline = tmp
                pass
            self.after(5, self.readfile)
            pass
        pass
#   def reload(self):
#       pass
    def start(self):
        self.start_stop = True
        self.readfile()
        pass
    def stop(self):
        self.start_stop = False
        pass
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Isaac Debug Helper")
    root.geometry("650x500")
    gui = GUI(root)
    gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you give us the error message? or is there none?

Comment: can you be more specific on what doesnt pack properly means?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't self.output.pack() come after the self.output.config()?

Comment: well, here's what the window look like : http://imgur.com/a/9da8p the buttons are displayed but not the Text widget, which should look like IDLE's text box

Comment: You must change `self.output = tk.Text(self)` to `self.output = tk.Text(self.frame)`

Comment: thanks the text widget now shows up, but not the buttons... I tried switching to another geometry manager (grid) and can't fix it

Comment: @Cribber: the order of `pack` and `config` is irrelevant.

Comment: For one thing, you are putting the text widget in a frame (`self.frame`) inside a frame (the instance of `GUI`). However, you aren't calling `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance of `GUI`. If `GUI` isn't visible, no children of `GUI` will be visible, either.

Comment: You also have the problem that you're creating an inner frame (`self.frame`) as a child of the root rather than a child of `GUI`. While that will work, it's not how you should be doing it. The whole point of making `GUI` inherit from `tk.Frame` is so that everything created by that class is inside that frame.

Comment: @BryanOakley so how should I proceed to code it properly ?

Comment: I think the only thing you are missing in the "new code" is putting the GUI in the root, I.E. `gui.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

The working complete code is here, thanks to everyone who helped !

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time
from os.path import expanduser

def get_log_path():
    p = ""
    if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
        p = expanduser("~/.local/share/binding of isaac afterbirth+/log.txt")
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        p = expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Binding of Isaac Afterbirth+/log.txt")
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        p = expanduser("~/Documents/My Games/binding of isaac afterbirth+/log.txt")
    return p
    pass

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.start_stop = False
        self.log_path = get_log_path()
        self.output = tk.Text(self)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Start", command=self.start)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Stop", command=self.stop)
        master.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.oldline = "  "
        self.init_layout()
        pass

    def init_layout(self):
        self.output.config(font="sans 10", width=200, height=60)
        self.output.tag_config("error", foreground="#FF0000")
        self.output.tag_config("warning", foreground="#00FF00")
        self.output.tag_config("info", foreground="#0000FF")
        self.output.pack()
        self.readfile()
        pass

    def readfile(self):
        if self.start_stop:
            tmp = self.log_f.readline().lower()
            if self.oldline != tmp: #display spam only once@FileLoad
                self.output.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                if "err" in tmp or "error" in tmp and not "overlayeffect" in tmp and not "animation" in tmp: #Error filter to display
                    self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp, "error")
                elif "lua" in tmp:
                    self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp, "info")
                elif "warn" in tmp:
                    self.output.insert(tk.END, tmp, "warning")
                self.oldline = tmp
            self.output.see(tk.END)
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.after(5, self.readfile)
            pass
        pass
    def start(self):
        self.log_f = open(self.log_path, "r")
        self.start_stop = True
        self.readfile()
        pass
    def stop(self):
        self.log_f.close()
        self.start_stop = False
        pass
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Isaac Debug Helper")
    root.geometry("650x500")
    gui = GUI(root)
    gui.pack()
    gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: you are neglecting to pass `master` to  ` super(GUI, self).__init__()`. It's harmless in this specific case since no master is the same as having `root` as the master, but in general you should get in the habit of passing it along.